# How to select all rows that have the max count and not only the first row?

Tags: sqlite

The aim is to select all the names of the persons who have drank all beers from tyskland. In this case, im looking to find the name of the person that has max(count) of beers from germany. I formed smaller tables along the way to try to get the result: From the table below :

```
table qwe
sysnr            beer                            land             namn
---------------  ------------------------------  ---------------  ---------------
1260             Guinness Draught                Irland           Agneta
11226            Gigantic IPA                    USA              Alan
11410            Alesmith Decadence              USA              Alan
11581            Trashy Blonde                   Storbritanien    Alan
1260             Guinness Draught                Irland           Alan
1403             Tuborg                          Danmark          Alan
1416             Lowenbrau                       Tyskland         Alan
1506             Jever                           Tyskland         Alan
1515             Punk IPA                        Storbritanien    Alan
1523             Armageddon IPA                  Nya Zeeland      Alan
1540             Westmalle Double                Belgien          Alan
1548             Brooklyn Lager                  USA              Alan
1553             Chang Beer                      Thailand         Alan
1559             Coors Light                     USA              Alan
1565             Bitburger                       Tyskland         Alan
1566             Pilsner Urquell                 Tjeckien         Alan
1574             Pabst Blue Ribbon Export        USA              Alan
1585             San Miguel                      Spanien          Alan
1594             Lapin Kulta                     Finland          Alan
1625             Sierra Nevada Pale Ale          USA              Alan
1642             Fullers London Pride            Storbritanien    Alan
1649             Samuel Adams Boston Ale         USA              Alan
1650             Orval                           Belgien          Alan
1654             Duvel                           Belgien          Alan
1657             Chimay vit                      Belgien          Alan
1659             Leffe Blond                     Belgien          Alan
1664             Kwak                            Belgien          Alan
1670             DAB                             Tyskland         Alan
1675             Anchor Steam Beer               USA              Alan
89607            Lagunitas IPA                   USA              Alan
89793            Maredsous Tripel                Belgien          Alan
11410            Alesmith Decadence              USA              Dick
1553             Chang Beer                      Thailand         Dick
1642             Fullers London Pride            Storbritanien    Dick
1222             Sofiero                         Sverige          Dina
1574             Pabst Blue Ribbon Export        USA              Dina
1650             Orval                           Belgien          Dina
11451            Pripps Bla                      Sverige          Fredrik
1403             Tuborg                          Danmark          Fredrik
1559             Coors Light                     USA              Fredrik
30611            Dugges High Five                Sverige          Fredrik
11489            Gambrinus                       Tjeckien         Henrik
1353             Budvar                          Tjeckien         Henrik
1544             Litovel Classic                 Tjeckien         Henrik
1566             Pilsner Urquell                 Tjeckien         Henrik
1611             Breznak                         Tjeckien         Henrik
89301            Bernard                         Tjeckien         Henrik
11410            Alesmith Decadence              USA              Janne
1260             Guinness Draught                Irland           Janne
1506             Jever                           Tyskland         Janne
1559             Coors Light                     USA              Janne
1649             Samuel Adams Boston Ale         USA              Janne
11410            Alesmith Decadence              USA              Johan
1515             Punk IPA                        Storbritanien    Johan
1548             Brooklyn Lager                  USA              Johan
1559             Coors Light                     USA              Johan
1670             DAB                             Tyskland         Johan
1403             Tuborg                          Danmark          Jonas
1403             Tuborg                          Danmark          Juha
1522             Karhu                           Finland          Juha
1523             Armageddon IPA                  Nya Zeeland      Juha
1566             Pilsner Urquell                 Tjeckien         Juha
1574             Pabst Blue Ribbon Export        USA              Juha
1594             Lapin Kulta                     Finland          Juha
30023            US Red Ale                      Finland          Juha
30658            Stigbergets Saison              Sverige          Juha
11433            Falcon Export                   Sverige          Kalle
1519             Saxon                           Finland          Kalle
1522             Karhu                           Finland          Kalle
1551             Citra Pale Ale                  Holland          Kalle
1594             Lapin Kulta                     Finland          Kalle
1675             Anchor Steam Beer               USA              Kalle
30023            US Red Ale                      Finland          Kalle
11433            Falcon Export                   Sverige          Kjell
1515             Punk IPA                        Storbritanien    Kjell
1548             Brooklyn Lager                  USA              Kjell
1559             Coors Light                     USA              Kjell
11226            Gigantic IPA                    USA              Lennart
11451            Pripps Bla                      Sverige          Lennart
11489            Gambrinus                       Tjeckien         Lennart
11581            Trashy Blonde                   Storbritanien    Lennart
1344             Amstel                          Holland          Lennart
1403             Tuborg                          Danmark          Lennart
1407             Backyard Brew                   Danmark          Lennart
1523             Armageddon IPA                  Nya Zeeland      Lennart
1540             Westmalle Double                Belgien          Lennart
1565             Bitburger                       Tyskland         Lennart
1566             Pilsner Urquell                 Tjeckien         Lennart
1574             Pabst Blue Ribbon Export        USA              Lennart
1594             Lapin Kulta                     Finland          Lennart
1642             Fullers London Pride            Storbritanien    Lennart
1650             Orval                           Belgien          Lennart
1659             Leffe Blond                     Belgien          Lennart
1664             Kwak                            Belgien          Lennart
1670             DAB                             Tyskland         Lennart
89793            Maredsous Tripel                Belgien          Lennart
1403             Tuborg                          Danmark          Lisen
1407             Backyard Brew                   Danmark          Lisen
1548             Brooklyn Lager                  USA              Lisen
1553             Chang Beer                      Thailand         Lisen
1565             Bitburger                       Tyskland         Lisen
1594             Lapin Kulta                     Finland          Lisen
1657             Chimay vit                      Belgien          Lisen
30611            Dugges High Five                Sverige          Lisen
30658            Stigbergets Saison              Sverige          Lisen
11410            Alesmith Decadence              USA              Magnus
1260             Guinness Draught                Irland           Magnus
1407             Backyard Brew                   Danmark          Maria
11451            Pripps Bla                      Sverige          Marie
11489            Gambrinus                       Tjeckien         Rikard
1353             Budvar                          Tjeckien         Rikard
1540             Westmalle Double                Belgien          Rikard
1544             Litovel Classic                 Tjeckien         Rikard
1611             Breznak                         Tjeckien         Rikard
1650             Orval                           Belgien          Rikard
1654             Duvel                           Belgien          Rikard
1657             Chimay vit                      Belgien          Rikard
1659             Leffe Blond                     Belgien          Rikard
1664             Kwak                            Belgien          Rikard
1670             DAB                             Tyskland         Rikard
89793            Maredsous Tripel                Belgien          Rikard
11410            Alesmith Decadence              USA              Urban
1416             Lowenbrau                       Tyskland         Urban
1506             Jever                           Tyskland         Urban
1565             Bitburger                       Tyskland         Urban
1642             Fullers London Pride            Storbritanien    Urban
1670             DAB                             Tyskland         Urban
```

I did:

```
create table zzz as select namn, count(land) as nrofbeerfromtyskland from qwe where land = 'Tyskland' group by namn;
```

```
namn                                                nrofbeerfromtyskland
--------------------------------------------------  --------------------------------------------------
Alan                                                4
Janne                                               1
Johan                                               1
Lennart                                             2
Lisen                                               1
Rikard                                              1
Urban                                               4
```

```
create view xxx as select namn, max(nrofbeerfromtyskland) from zzz;
```

```
namn                                                max(nrofbeerfromtyskland)
--------------------------------------------------  --------------------------------------------------
Alan                                                4
```

The result should be:

```
Alan
Urban
```

How does one not make it to only show Alan in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`RANK()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) window function:

```
select t.namn
from (
  select namn, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
  from qwe
  where land = 'Tyskland'
  group by namn
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xgtpr3YhfCgASdGYSuyrNq/0).
This query returns all the persons who drank the most beers from 'Tyskland'.
If you want only the persons who drank **all** the beers from 'Tyskland' then use this:

```
select namn
from qwe
where land = 'Tyskland'
group by namn
having count(distinct beer) = (select count(distinct beer) from qwe where land = 'Tyskland')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xgtpr3YhfCgASdGYSuyrNq/1).
Results:

```
| namn  |
| ----- |
| Alan  |
| Urban |
```

Comment: Salute to you my friend !!